# Animation does not play

Tags: animation

I have imported an fbx that contains an animation.
However, it doesn't play in Blender.
I don't see why.
Can anybody help?

Thank you!

[Here is the fbx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aAbTAssM6SHghw1c8henLJKjotrCAT01/view?usp=sharing).

[image]

Comment: It does work the only problem was that there were too many pointless keyframes with the same rotation, scale, and location. Go to pose mode and move some bones then insert keyframes.

Comment: @JacksonPro Does it move for you? I switch to Pose mode, I have the Timeline selected, and I press Play. Nothing happens for me.

Comment: Nothing happens because all keyframes have constant values. And the bone orientations are strange because the rig import was incorrect. Is it possible to upload the fbx?

Comment: @tetii Thank you. I have added it to my posting. I have opened it up in Autodesk FBX Review, and I don't see the animation playing there either. So strange. I will post here if I see what goes on here.

Comment: not only that the animation is not properly...the rig isn't either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the fbx file doesn't seem to contain any useful animation data. You can check the animation data with the graph editor.

[image]

On the other hand, if you check *Force Connect Children* and *Automatic Bone Orientation*, bone orientations will be aligned.

[image]